# zend db select table doesn't exist error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So I'm trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT r.refID AS rID, avgrat FROM rcc r;
```

with `Zend_Db_Select`

So I have this code:

```
$sql = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from(array("r" => "rcc"), array("rID" => "refID"), "avgrat");
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But then I get mysql db error which complains that Base table or view not found: 1146 table avgrat.rcc doesn't exist..

even though the table does indeed exist

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Try your sql in command line. Is it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you're passing `avgrat` as the third parameter to `from()`, which is actually for setting the `$schema`. So, unless your database is actually named `avgrat` then try:

```
$sql->from(array('r' => 'rcc'), array('rID' => 'refID', 'avgrat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this table exist in the database?

Try this

```
$sql = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from(array("r" => "rcc"), array("refID AS rID"), "avgrat");
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll()
```